Value of permittivity inside an atom
As we know, the permittivity of free space physically measures how dense an electric field can form in response to electric charges in free space. I have the following 2 questions:

What will be the value of permittivity inside an atom?
Does it remain the same? If yes, then why does it happen so?


When you say "inside an atom", do you mean 1) at radii smaller than the expectation value of the electron radius but greater than the nucleus radius, or 2) inside the nucleus, or 3) something else?

By "inside an atom," I mean space between atomic nucleus and electron cloud. Would it be vacuum? Also, would the answer depend on where we measure the value inside the atom?

Remember that the probability distribution of an $s$ state is a maximum at the nucleus. There is no ‘space between atomic nucleus and electron cloud’.

Okay, I got it. So, is my question valid? About finding the value of permittivity inside an atom?
